# Argument of type '{ count: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number

Tags: angular, rxjs5

With this code

```
const start$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.getNativeElement(this.start),'click');
    const stop$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.getNativeElement(this.stop),'click');
    const interval$ = Observable.interval(1000);
    const data = {count:0};

    const intervalThatStops$ = interval$
    .takeUntil(stop$);

start$
    .switchMapTo(intervalThatStops$)
    .startWith(data)
    .scan((acc,curr) => {
      return {
        count: acc.count+1
      };
    })
    .subscribe((x)=> console.log(x.count));
```

I've got in the console

*Argument of type '{ count: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number | IScheduler'.
  Type '{ count: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IScheduler'.
    Property 'now' is missing in type '{ count: number; }'.)*

a quick fix should be

```
.startWith<any>(data)
```

but what's the right way, please ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Taking it in parts,

```
start$
    .switchMapTo(intervalThatStops$)
    .startWith(data)
```

After that switchMapTo, your resulting Observable will emit values from the intervalThatStops$. And intervalThatStops$ is emitting pure numbers. So, when you try to `.startWith({count:0})`, you get the Typescript error because your observable is emitting numbers, but you're trying to startWith an object ({count: 0}).

The solution is to map your intervalThatStops$ to your object BEFORE using the startWith.

You can do this numerous ways - one possibility is:

```
start$
    .switchMapTo(intervalThatStops$)
    .map(i => ({count: i})))
    .startWith(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply using map you can avoid .startWith(data) and it doesn't seem very clean as solution all in all I want my startWith

Comment: well, the first emission from the interval operator is 0, so as you said, you don't really need a 'startWith'